# Decompile pyc in 2.7 in python 3 env

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.7, decompiler, pyc

I have a package of the of python. All are in pyc. I need to decompile the same. I tried uncompyle6. But when I do the same I am getting the below file entry only in the output.

```
# uncompyle6 version 3.7.4
# Python bytecode 2.7 (62211)
# Decompiled from: Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 19:28:38) 
# [GCC 7.3.0]
# Embedded file name: G:\Packages\source\source_8.5.3\mysite\i18n_backend.py
# Compiled at: 2020-04-21 12:12:30
```

I suppose that this is because the pyc is compiled in the python 2.7 and I am trying to decompile the same in python 3.7. As my ubuntu doesn't have 2.7, how can I go forward now? There are more than 200 files, that also in subdirectories.

Comment: Install 2.7, and use it? Python 3 isn't keeping around a 2.7 parser for funsies.

Comment: I installed python in a windows system and setup the uncompyle6. But when running now I am getting the below error. Please help.

Comment: `
IndexError: tuple index out of range`

Comment: @ShadowRanger uncompyle6 does not require you do install the Python interpreter for the bytecode that you want to decompile. Specifically, you can decompile Python 2.7 bytecode from Python 3.7 running uncomplye6. Similarly, aside from problems imposed by unicode handling, you can often decompile 3.7 bytecode from Python2.7 running uncompyle6. (Decompiling from Python 3.x  handles the unicode problems).  Decompiling bytecode doesn't require using the CPython interperter's parser outside of the usual Python parsing of the *uncompyle6* code unless you start from byte-compiled uncompyle6.